# Attached file in PHP form not sending through to email address

Tags: php, forms, email-attachments

I have created a simple PHP email quote request form with file attachment here
http://www.cmipromotions.com/upload-file-test-form/
when I submit the form with an attachment, an email is sent to the recipient normally, but there is no file attachment with the email.  I am not receiving any error messages.
Here is the Form HTML code:

```
    <div style="background-image: url('/images/cmi_horizontal_quote_request_form_bg_slim.gif'); background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 227px; width: 520px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;"><form action="../contact-form-handlerUpload.php" method="POST" name="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table style="width: 520px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 280px;">
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; padding-top: 50px;"><input id="mattfield" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 2px 5px; width: 200px;" onfocus="if (this.value=='Name') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Name';" type="text" name="name" value="Name" /></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;"><input id="mattfield" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 2px 5px; width: 200px;" onfocus="if (this.value=='Email') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Email';" type="text" name="email" value="Email" /></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;"><input id="mattfield" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 2px 5px; width: 200px;" onfocus="if (this.value=='Company') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Company';" type="text" name="company" value="Company" /></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;"><input id="mattfield" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 2px 5px; width: 200px;" onfocus="if (this.value=='Phone') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Phone';" type="text" name="phone" value="Phone" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><textarea style="width:200px; max-width: 200px; height: 25px; max-height:30px; border-width: 0.5px;" name="message"></textarea></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 280px;">
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; padding-top: 14px;"><input id="mattfield" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 2px 5px; width: 200px;" onfocus="if (this.value=='Product#') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Product#';" type="text" name="product" value="Product#" /></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;"><input id="mattfield" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 2px 5px; width: 200px;" onfocus="if (this.value=='Quantity (100pc min)') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Quantity (100pc min)';" type="text" name="quantity" value="Quantity (100pc min)" /></p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;"><input id="mattfield" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 2px 5px; width: 200px;" onfocus="if (this.value=='Upload File') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Upload File';" type="file" multiple="false" name="uploadfile" value="Upload File" /></p>

<div style="color: black; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width: 130px;">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Capacity</td>
<td><select id="capacity" name="capacity"> <option style="padding-bottom: 2px;" selected="selected" value="1GB">1GB</option> <option style="padding-bottom: 2px;" value="2GB">2GB</option> <option style="padding-bottom: 2px;" value="4GB">4GB</option> <option style="padding-bottom: 2px;" value="8GB">8GB</option> <option style="padding-bottom: 2px;" value="16GB">16GB</option> <option style="padding-bottom: 2px;" value="32GB">32GB</option><option style="padding-bottom: 2px;" value="64MB">64MB</option><option style="padding-bottom: 2px;" value="128MB">128MB</option><option style="padding-bottom: 2px;" value="256MB">256MB</option> <option style="padding-bottom: 2px;" value="512MB">512MB</option> </select></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<center><input id="mattcool" style="background-image: url('/images/CMI_horizontal_quote_button3.gif'); height: 37px; border: 0px none; width: 178px; position: inherit; transition: none;" type="submit" value="" /></center></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">// <![CDATA[
// Code for validating the form // Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml // for details var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactform"); frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name");  frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email");
// ]]></script>

</div>
<br>
```

and here is the php

```
    <?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'myaddress@myaddress.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 

   empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Name & Email are required";
}
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));





    //*** Attachment ***//  
    if($_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"] != "")  
    {  
    $strFilesName = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];  
    $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"])));  
    $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";  
    $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n";  
    $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";  
    $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";  
    $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";  
    }  

    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; 
    $product = $_POST['product']; 
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity']; 
    $capacity = $_POST['capacity']; 
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $pagetitle = $_POST['pagetitle'];



if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "New Inquiry Form Submission from: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new lead from the $pagetitle page \n Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Company: $company \n Email: $email_address \n Phone Number: $phone \n Product #: $product \n Page Title: $pagetitle \n Quantity: $quantity \n Capacity: $capacity \n Message: \n $message"; 






    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    $spam_error_message = "No SPAM Permitted";
    if (preg_match("/http/i", "$name")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/http/i", "$email_address")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/http/i", "$company")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/http/i", "$phone")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/http/i", "$message")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/http/i", "$product")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/http/i", "$quantity")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/http/i", "$capacity")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}

    if (preg_match("/www/i", "$name")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/www/i", "$email_address")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/www/i", "$company")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/www/i", "$phone")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/www/i", "$message")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/www/i", "$product")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/www/i", "$quantity")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}
    if (preg_match("/www/i", "$capacity")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}  if (preg_match("/katieskittles/", "$email_address")) {echo "$spam_error_message";  exit();}




    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers,$strHeader);

    mail($email_address,"Thank you for contacting CMI Promotions","Thank you for contacting CMI Promotions.\nYour request has been received and we will respond to you shortly. \nOur normal business hours are M-F 8:30 am to 5:00 pm PST.  \nAll Inquiries received on weekends or after hours will be addressed the following business day. \nYou are also welcome to contact us directly at 855-463-3080 if you need immediate assistance.",$headers);


    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: http://www.cmipromotions.com/thank-you-for-your-inquiry/');
} 
?>
```

Any help that you can give me would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I super-highly recommend using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) because I have battled with attachments before and they are obnoxiously hard.

I must have wrote over 300 lines of code to get attachments to work in an HTML email and I felt like kicking myself when I discovered PHPMailer.